# How to get the quantity of products in specified date in odoo 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I want to create table in odoo 10 with the following columns: quantity_in_the_first_day_of_month,input_quantity,output_quantity,quantity_in_the_last_day_of_the_month.

but i don't know how to get the quantity  of the specified date

Comment: I think you need an sql request on sale_order table join with sale_order_line join with product_template where sale_order state is done and date order between start_date and end_date

Answer (score 0):

You can join the sale order and sale order line to get specified date.

select 
    sum(sol.product_uom_qty)
from 
    sale_order s,sale_order_line sol 
where 
    sol.order_id=s.id and
    DATE(s.date_order) = '2018-01-01'